# Python: Traceback namerror

Tags: python, urllib, httplib

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
  File "wexec.py", line 37, in <module>
   urlopen = urllib.urlopen('%xs' % (hcon))
NameError: name 'hcon' is not defined
```

I get this problem by doing this code in python:

```
def hell():

    hcon = raw_input(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + "Website: ")
    h1 = httplib.HTTPConnection('%s' % (hcon))
    urlopen = urllib.urlopen('%s' % (hcon))

hell()
```

As you can see, I don't see any problem with it at all. But something is giving it this error. What do I do?

Comment: The `urlopen` line doesn't appear to be part of the function -- it needs to have the same indentation as the lines above it.

Comment: Is the indentation on SO the same as in your code?

Comment: I fixed the identation but now I get this:
`httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: 'website'` I didn't use website but I used http://www.rile5.com for example.

Comment: Fix the indentation *in your question* so that when we copy and paste your code it's the same as what you're running.  And update your question with the new error message.  Then we can give you better answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason you're getting the nonnumeric port error is because you're passing HTTPConnection the entire string "Website: website" and it expects a port number after a colon (see the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection)

Comment: @snorthway why would that be the case?

Comment: @snorthway no, `raw_input` will parse that for him and only supply the string after website:

Comment: @snorthway The port thing helped me but as raw_input has no problems. Thanks.

Comment: @limelights Ah right, my bad. Nevermind.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `'%s' % (hcon)`? As far as I can tell, `hcon` is already going to be a string, and so you should be able to use it directly. If it's not a string for some reason, `str(hcon)` would probably be clearer.